# Apache+php doesn't open php script from certain directory

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have two directories in `/var/www`:

```
root@user:/var/www# ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      4096 Июл 14 17:59 first
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      4096 Июл 14 18:00 second
```

with exactly the same php scripts:

```
root@user:/var/www# ls -l first/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Июл 14 16:37 info.php

root@user:/var/www# ls -l second/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Июл 14 16:37 info.php
```

info.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

But from the `first/` directory Apache opens script, from the `second/` pulls error:

```
( ! ) Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/second/info.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

What can be a reason?

Directory config:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www"

<Directory "/var/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are there any other files in those directories? Can you post your apache config for the host and directory?

Comment: @oliakaoil There're no other files in these dirs. I'm new to configure  Apache+Php, so I added block "Directory" from "apache2.conf". Shall I add smth else?

Comment: maybe an issue with your open_basedir setting? Also seems strange that your document root is root owned.

Comment: @oliakaoil open_basedir setting is not set, "/var/www/" directory has all permissions

Comment: Could you try, `sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www` after that `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I'm really sorry, I missclicked and choosed wrong question to start bounty :)

Comment: maybe selinux, try checking the state with sestatus and if its enforced list a ls -Z /var/www

Comment: ...and check for .htaccess files and directory specific configurations in the httpd.conf

Comment: @AdemÖztaş I guess you mean **www-data:www-data** (column there)

Comment: @sitilge www-data:ww-data or www-data.www-data ,all of them correct on the linux

Comment: Can you post a `hexdump` of both PHP files? I see that your date is not in Latin script, so there may be some Unicode stuff at the start of one of the files.

Comment: Can you post all the contents of both files? I'm wondering if there is something in the second file that is causing the problem. I tried duplicating the exact same folders/permissions and don't see any issue; so it's possibly the content of the script file. Even hidden characters...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the owner of the two folders from 'root' to apache.

Try sudo chown -R **[yourusername]**:www-data /var/www

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of things to try here 
1) What folder has your `.htaccess`? 
2) The error you provides hints that php would look for scripts in include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear'
This points that the script is to be present in the following paths only. 
3) You may want to check if ls -Z may reveal the difference in the security context of the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SeLinux Context is the thing you need to set. In this case:

```
ls -lZ
```

if you got something like

```
rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
```

OR

```
 drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
```

You need to run

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www
```

Then you will have

```
drwxr-xr-x  root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/
```

Something like this

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Comment: And how exactly switching to *lower* permission set would solve the problem? Makes no sense here.

Comment: For sitilge; on some systems files and folders MUST have specific permissions to be accessible for the script (apache web server). 'failed to open stream' in general is most often connected to problems with permissions.

Comment: @sitilge I did a little searching because I was curious too. http://serverfault.com/questions/390484/suexec-group-writeable-files

Comment: exactly some times specific permissions are required, too open sometimes is too unsafe :)

Comment: Why the fix works:  It is a security weakness to have these files writable by the world, especially those marked as executables and owned by ROOT.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

The group is root probably thats the issue

Answer (score -2):

You could also have tried:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www
```

Comment: System dependent but irrelevant here since the 777 permission set to both dir and file.

Comment: on fedora core this works well not quite sure about other platforms i have used this command more than once  but i would not say apache:apache this will make it a bit difficult for you to edit the site files on your local machine i simply use this command sudo chown my_current_name:apache -R /var/www